# Can't do AWS API Gateway Mapping using a Mock Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm using the Okta Identity provider and I want to setup an automated process that triggers when a new users is added via Okta in AWS. Okta supports this via a process called Event Hooks. They send out a message when a condition is met to an endpoint you configure. This message contains the information I need.

My current plan is to use an AWS API GW to pick up the message, transfer it to SQS and then SQS to Lambda. I've got everything up to the connection between the AWS API GW and Okta working.

Okta require the following:

> The way your service needs to handle this one-time verification is as follows: The request from Okta contains an HTTP header named x-okta-verification-challenge. Your service needs to read the value of that header and return it in the response body, in a JSON object named verification: that is: { "verification" : "value_from_header" }. The value_from_header is found in the request HTTP header, but you need to send it back in a JSON object.

To enable this I've setup an API GW endpoint with both a POST and GET method. For the GET I think it makes sense to use a Mock Integration as I only need to transform the response body.

My issue is that the docs don't seem very clear on how to do this. I know I need to modify the Mapping Template underneath the GET - Method Execution > Mock Integration Request, I'm just not sure how.

I would really like some help in understanding how I can parse the headers from a get and put them into the body?

This is compounded by the issue that whenever I try to run tests locally, I get a no data value in the response body, even when I try to set it manually.

I've tried multiple templates in the hope that when i ran the test function I could see new results. The latest is this:

```json
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": {
    "message": "Go ahead without me."
  }
}
```

`StatusCode` part works fine. If I change it to 500 the test will fall over. I just can't seem to get anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you gotta tell AWS that you're expecting the "x-okta-verification-challenge" header in the incoming request.

Click on your GET method and open the "HTTP Request Headers" section.
Hit "Add header" and put "x-okta-verification-challenge" in there.

As for the Mapping Template for the Mock Integration, click on "Integration Request" in your GET method.
Expand "Mapping Templates" and add a new one with "application/json" as the content type.
Now, the crucial part: the template.
Here's how your template should look:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": "{\"verification\" : \"$input.params('x-okta-verification-challenge')\"}"
}
```

We're setting up a JSON with a "200 OK" statusCode, a "Content-Type" header of "application/json", and a body which is the verification challenge.

$input.params('x-okta-verification-challenge') is the trick to grab the value of the incoming "x-okta-verification-challenge" header.

Make sure you save everything.

When testing this, don't forget to include the "x-okta-verification-challenge" header with a value in your test request.

If your response body is still empty, double-check the header in your test request and make sure your mapping template is saved correctly. If there's a typo or something, API Gateway might not save it right.